# createing wamp server with cygwin?

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, cygwin, wamp

i notice that in cygwin we can install apache2.
can we make a wamp with cgywin ? ( php mysql and apache ) better with phpmyadmin ? or we cant do that ? if we can, please give me a tutorial to learn on.

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do that? PHP MySQL and Apache all have Windows versions, why not use them.

Comment: For example because the native binaries use Windows paths. I could think of some other setups where having a xamp system inside the cygwin environment could be more useful than the native expression.

Comment: How was this considered an answer to the question? It's fit for a comment at best. FYI, there are various possible rationales for this, including Boldewyn's plus a need to replicate or test a POSIX-style environment with these programs installed. I want the latter, so now I have to go and look for a question that actually received a valid answer.